# mysql++ query crashes on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql++

Here I wrote simplest program to reproduce my crash inside mysqlpp::Connection::query():

```
#include <mysql++.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
    if (conn.connect("neutrino", "localhost", "root", "1"))
    {
        mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query("select 1;");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)
project (mysqlpptest)

add_executable(mysqlpptest main.cpp)

target_include_directories(mysqlpptest
    PRIVATE
        /usr/include/mysql
        /usr/include/mysql++
)

target_link_libraries(mysqlpptest
        -lmysqlclient
        -lmysqlpp
)
```

Everything is compiled and linked well, but query() crashes with segmentation fault.

Database is created, so connect() returns true. Here is also mysql terminal test:

```
glaz@glaz-linux:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 190
Server version: 5.6.25-0ubuntu0.15.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use neutrino;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select 1;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Any ideas where to dig the crash?

Updated: Call stack is useless because libraries are without debuggin info:

```
?? ()
std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > std::num_get<char, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::_M_extract_int<unsigned short>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, unsigned short&) const ()
std::num_get<char, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > >::do_get(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::ios_base&, std::_Ios_Iostate&, unsigned short&) const ()
std::ostream::seekp(long, std::_Ios_Seekdir) ()
mysqlpp::Query::Query(mysqlpp::Connection*, bool, char const*) ()
mysqlpp::Connection::query(char const*) ()
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffded8)
```

Comment: Power up the debugger and see where it jams? You need to go back through the stack and see what's wrong here. Also try compiling on different platforms if you can to narrow down the problem. You might want to try the one-shot constructor and then check `connected()` to see if it worked out.

Comment: I tried on Win7 64 with Visual Studio - OK. Call stack is useless, because libraries are release. I updated the question with the call stack - there are only functions' names.

Comment: Have access to any other distributions to try it on? Windows is an odd bird compared to most.

Comment: I tried at clean Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in VirtualBox - the sample doesn't crash. Looks like my distribution has some corruption. I will try on clean 15.04 in virtualbox.

Comment: On clean Ubuntu 15.04 works ok. Looks like I have corrupted packages or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had g++ updated from 4.9.2 to 5.1.1 at the system where the crash occurred. And for a some reason the code compiled by the later compiler was incompatible with mysql libraries (obviously compiled by 4.9.2 compiler). I reverted the compiler back to 4.9.2 (which originally comes with ubuntu 15.04) and everything became work well.